# Django not recognising custom field when migrating

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm using the following custom field (which I found online, though I forget where):

```
class ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(models.FileField):

def __init__(self, content_types=None, max_upload_size=None, *args, **kwargs):
    self.content_types = content_types
    self.max_upload_size = max_upload_size

    super(ContentTypeRestrictedFileField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    data = super(ContentTypeRestrictedFileField, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    file = data.file
    try:
        content_type = file.content_type
        if content_type in self.content_types:
            if file._size > self.max_upload_size:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(self.max_upload_size), filesizeformat(file._size)))
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('File type not supported. Must be a pdf or jpeg.'))
    except AttributeError:
        pass        

    return data

def deconstruct(self):
    name, path, args, kwargs = super(ContentTypeRestrictedFileField, self).deconstruct()
    if (self.content_types is not None):
        kwargs['content_types'] = self.content_types
    if (self.max_upload_size is not None):
        kwargs['max_upload_size'] = self.max_upload_size
    return name, path, args, kwargs
```

It's contained within my models.py file, which contains all of my models. All of them. I'm using the field in the following model, which is, again, defined in the same file as the custom field:

```
class AnswerModel(models.Model):

id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
application_id = models.ForeignKey(ApplicationModel, related_name="answers")
question_id = models.ForeignKey(QuestionModel, related_name="answers")
answer = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=1, default=NOT_ANSWERED)
upload = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(
    upload_to=get_file_upload_path,
    content_types=['application/pdf', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'],
    max_upload_size=2621440, # 2.5MB
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.answer

def __str__(self):
    return self.answer
```

Though when I attempt to migrate, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ContentTypeRestrictedFileField'
```

This makes no sense to me since it's defined before it's used, within the same file.

I can't find any answers anywhere else; does anyone have any idea?

Cheers.

Here's the full traceback:

```
    Development\Documents\GitHub\GKApplication\gk>manage.py migrate gk_models > traceback.txt
 (most recent call last):
:\Users\Development\Documents\GitHub\GKApplication\gk\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
te_from_command_line(sys.argv)
:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
ty.execute()
:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 338, in execute
t = self.handle(*args, **options)
:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 63, in handle
tor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 17, in __init__
loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 48, in __init__
build_graph()
:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 173, in build_graph
load_disk()
:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 103, in load_disk
tion_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))
:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
ort__(name)
:\Users\Development\Documents\GitHub\GKApplication\gk\gk_models\migrations\0001_initial.py", line 10, in <mod

 Migration(migrations.Migration):
:\Users\Development\Documents\GitHub\GKApplication\gk\gk_models\migrations\0001_initial.py", line 79, in Migr

oad', gk_models.models.ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(content_types=[b'application/pdf', b'image/jpeg', b'image/png'], ma
size=2621440, null=True, upload_to=gk_models.models.get_file_upload_path, blank=True)),
Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'ContentTypeRestrictedFileField'
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. You must be referring to it as `models. ContentTypeRestrictedFileField` somewhere, otherwise the exception would be `NameError: name ... is not defined`.

Comment: I've supplied the full traceback above. I've also checked through the file and there's only one instance of the field and that's exactly as shown above.

Comment: In the 0001_initial.py it's correctly (I believe) importing ContentTypeRestrictedFileField from gk_models.models, as it says. In my gk_models init.py I'm importing everything from the models file as well.